# How to disable a User Control to draw it's background (or Region)

Tags: c#, winforms, background

My question : **How to disable a User Control to draw it's background (or Region)**

Note : I already tried to override and empty OnPaintBackground or set background color to transparent.

I'm trying to bypass winform paint for my custom user controls in a custom container.
For that I thought to give a try to this : [Beginners-Starting-a-2D-Game-with-GDIplus](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/409988/Beginners-Starting-a-2D-Game-with-GDIplus)

My setup is :

- A Form containing:

  - A User control (DrawingBoard)
  - A Container with elements I can drag and drop to this DrawingBoard (it's a listbox).

My render loop is inside the DrawingBoard with all elements specified in the previous link.

```
public DrawingBoard()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Resize event are ignored
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.FixedHeight, true);
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.FixedWidth, true);
    SetStyle(System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);// True is better
    SetStyle(System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true); // True is better
    // Disable the on built PAINT event. We dont need it with a renderloop.
    // The form will no longer refresh itself
    // we will raise the paint event ourselves from our renderloop.
    SetStyle(System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.UserPaint, false); // False is better
}

#region GDI+ RENDERING
public Timer t = new Timer();
//This is your BackBuffer, a Bitmap:
Bitmap B_BUFFER = null;
//This is the surface that allows you to draw on your backbuffer bitmap.
Graphics G_BUFFER = null;
//This is the surface you will use to draw your backbuffer to your display.
Graphics G_TARGET = null;
Size DisplaySize = new Size(1120, 630);
bool Antialiasing = false;

const int MS_REDRAW = 32;

public void GDIInit()
{
    B_BUFFER = new Bitmap(DisplaySize.Width, DisplaySize.Height);
    G_BUFFER = Graphics.FromImage(B_BUFFER); //drawing surface
    G_TARGET = CreateGraphics();

    // Configure the display (target) graphics for the fastest rendering.
    G_TARGET.CompositingMode    = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
    G_TARGET.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.AssumeLinear;
    G_TARGET.SmoothingMode      = SmoothingMode.None;
    G_TARGET.InterpolationMode  = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
    G_TARGET.TextRenderingHint  = TextRenderingHint.SystemDefault;
    G_TARGET.PixelOffsetMode    = PixelOffsetMode.HighSpeed;

    // Configure the backbuffer's drawing surface for optimal rendering with optional
    // antialiasing for Text and Polygon Shapes            
    //Antialiasing is a boolean that tells us weather to enable antialiasing.
    //It is declared somewhere else
    if (Antialiasing)
    {
        G_BUFFER.SmoothingMode      = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        G_BUFFER.TextRenderingHint  = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
    }
    else
    {
        // No Text or Polygon smoothing is applied by default
        G_BUFFER.CompositingMode    = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
        G_BUFFER.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
        G_BUFFER.InterpolationMode  = InterpolationMode.Low;
        G_BUFFER.PixelOffsetMode    = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
    }

    t.Tick += RenderingLoop;
    t.Interval = MS_REDRAW;
    t.Start();
}
void RenderingLoop(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        G_BUFFER.Clear(Color.DarkSlateGray);
        UIPaint(G_BUFFER);
        G_TARGET.DrawImageUnscaled(B_BUFFER, 0, 0);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
#endregion
```

Then my elements get the event fired and try to draw what I would like:

```
public override void UIPaint(Graphics g)
{     
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Blue,4);
    p.Alignment = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Inset;          
    g.DrawLines(p, new Point[] { new Point(Location.X, Location.Y), new Point(Location.X + Width, Location.Y), new Point(Location.X + Width, Location.Y + Height), new Point(Location.X, Location.Y + Height), new Point(Location.X, Location.Y - 2) });

    g.DrawImageUnscaled(GDATA.GetWindowImage(), Location);        
    }
```

here is what happening on my DrawingBoard :

As I can't post image ... here is the link : http://s8.postimage.org/iqpxtaoht/Winform.jpg

- The background is DarkSlateGray because my G_BUFFER state to clear each tick with that, Ok
- The blue rectangle is what I paint, but it get cropped, KO
- The Texture is cropped, KO
- The region that crop my drawing is the control size.

So from there I've tried everything I could to disable WinForm to make some magic drawing in background. Tried to override and empty everything that got paint/update/refresh/invalidate/validate on Form/DrawingBoard/Elements but nothing allowed me to get my texture or drawing to not get cropped by the control background : (

I also tried to set the background of the Element as transparent and also to set Form.TransparencyKey = blabla with each element BackColor = blabla. But failed each time.

I'm certainly missing something : / But I don't know what.

Comment: I would recommend throwing winforms away and whatever graphics you need would be easier to do (and look better) in WPF

Comment: Well I'm stuck with WinForm as it's part of a bigger App :^( but thx for the input, I might try WPF next time i have to create UI

Comment: not really, there is an [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) element you can use to host WPF content inside a winforms app. It has some drawbacks, but it's going to be 1000% easier than trying to do anything useful in winforms, which requires 123123123030912 lines of code, whereas WPF gives you a whole lot more flexibility and power

Comment: Yeah but I would have to convert all my elements. And learn WPF. I'm not against it but I don't have enough time : / I ~just~ need to avoid the crop happening and I would be good to go

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you want to draw the background? To avoid problems with flickering in my custom control (derived from class `Control`), here's what I did:

(1) override `OnPaintBackground`:

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
{
}
```

(2) Draw in an offscreen `Bitmap` and then transfer it to the screen:

```
Bitmap _completeFrame;
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
    DrawFrame(); // draws onto _completeFrame, calling new Bitmap() 
                 // when _completeFrame is null or its Size is wrong
    var g = pe.Graphics;
    g.DrawImage(_completeFrame, new Point());
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't setting the UserControl to use a Double Buffer do the sane thing here,

Comment: I don't know, haven't tried it. If it works, OP was making a game, so he'll probably want good performance and I don't know if `Control.DoubleBuffered` will be the same speed.